# How to delete custom form in Outlook 2013 using Outlook object model?

Tags: outlook, outlook-2013

I created an custom form in Outlook 2013 named as "Service Request" and then it was published. Now to access the custom form a menu option is available under "New Items".

`New Items---->Custom Form----->Service Request`

I know the way to delete this menu item manually, by following the way

`File--->Options--->Advanced---->Developer--->Custom Form--->Form Pattern`

But my requirement is, need to delete the menu item programmatically using OOM in Outlook 2013.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook Object Model does not allow to do that. You will need to use the [IMAPIFormMgr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc842242%28v=office.15%29.aspx) MAPI interface (C++ or Delphi only)